# Increment function argument variable [Python]

Tags: python, excel, while-loop, nested, xlrd

I am trying to write a script that reads from an Excel file as a template, and then insert new data based on what is read from a .txt file.

I am using the `xlrd` module for reading. Currently, I am stuck at the reading portion  of the script.

I plan to increment the `rowx` and `colx` argument variable by 1 each time, so each cell is searched in the Excel file. However, it appears that Python's argument variables cannot be modified ?

The increment in my script modifies the external variable instead. Is there any way to achieve the cell-by-cell value searching ?

```
# Define variables
switch1 = 1
count = 0
rowx = 0
colx = 0

# Loop 
while switch1 == 1 and count < totalCells:    
    print "AAAA"

    cellValue = "Long string in here....."

    if sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0) == cellValue:
        print "BBBB"
        switch1 = 0

    rowx    += 1
    colx    += 1    
    count   += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *use* the `rowx` and `colx` variables. You always just pass 0:

```
if sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0) == cellValue:
```

Pass in the values of your variables instead:

```
if sh.cell_value(rowx=rowx, colx=colx) == cellValue:
```

While you're at it, you can make some other simplifications. `rowx` and `colx` are always the same as `count`, so you can just use one variable. We can loop from `0` to `totalCells-1` with a `for` loop, and end the loop early with a `break` statement:

```
for i in xrange(totalCells):
    print "AAAA"
    cellValue = "Long string in here....."
    if sh.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=i) == cellValue:
        print "BBBB"
        break
```

If `rowx` and `colx` were not intended to always be the same, you'll need to fix that, because otherwise you'll just be going along the main diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Oh yes you're right, the `rowx` and `colx` cannot always be of the same value if I want to iterate through each cell in the Excel file.. Will work on that.